# MVC with Entity Framework Drop down list assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was given a [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOiFs2) which helps me assign a Ticket to a user with Admin status through a drop down menu. I'm having trouble following the code in the controller and don't know if I did it correctly.

Error:
[image]

[image]

Code I'm trying to convert's TicketController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TicketVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Initialise a new data model
    // Set the author based on the current user
    // Set the other properties based on the view model e.g
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket
    {
        // Author = xxx
        Issue = model.Issue,
        IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo 
    };
    // Save the data model and redirect e.g.
    //db.Users.Add(ticket);
    //db.SaveChanges();

    // Cant have more than one view in DotNetFiddle so just return the view
    return View(model);
}
```

TicketController.cs (My Code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    public class TicketController : Controller
    {
        private IssueContext db = new IssueContext();

        //
        // GET: /Ticket/

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ConfigureViewModel(model);
                return View(model);
            }
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket { 

            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo
        };

            return View(model);

    }
    private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
    {


        IEnumerable<User> admins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
        model.AdministratorList = admins.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.UserID.ToString(),
            Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstMidName, a.LastName)
        });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Ticket/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
            if (ticket == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ticket);
        }

        // POST: /Ticket/Create 


        //
        // GET: /Ticket/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
            if (ticket == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", ticket.CategoryID);
            ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserID", "LastName", ticket.UserID);
            return View(ticket);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Ticket/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(TicketVM model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ConfigureViewModel(model);
                return View(model);
            }
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket
            {
                // Author = xxx
                Issue = model.Issue,
                IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo
            };
            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", ticket.CategoryID);
            ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserID", "LastName", ticket.UserID);
            return View(ticket);

        }


        //
        // GET: /Ticket/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
            if (ticket == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ticket);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Ticket/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
            db.Tickets.Remove(ticket);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low, Med, High
}
public class Ticket
{
    public int? TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int Author { get; set; }
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }

}
```

\ViewModels\TicketVM.cs

```
public class TicketVM
{
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AdministratorList { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

\Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Issue)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Issue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Issue)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "User")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
       </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllUsers, "Please select")`
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
            </div>


        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TicketID)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Issue)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Issue, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Issue)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IssuedTo, Model.AdministratorList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Save</button>


            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: do you have @model TicketVM in your view?  Typically it's the first line.

Comment: So what is the problem ? Are you getting a compile time error ? Or are you having trouble rendering the dropdown items ? or you have trouble reading the selected dropdown option in your HttpPost method ? What is it ?

Comment: If you use the "For" syntax for the HtmlHelper in your views, you need to use a ViewModel. It looks like in your Create view, you are using the ViewBag. Try using the "non-For" versions of those calls instead

Comment: @Shyju I've listed the errors in the code. Compile time errors.

Comment: Use `Model.AdministratorList`

Comment: @Duston I added`@model IEnumerable < RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.TicketVM>` and it's giving me errors on UserID,Issue,TicketID,IssuedTo

Comment: @DCruz22 AdministratorList gives me "Ticket does not contain a definiton for 'AdministratorList'

Comment: @Jason Wan is this the namespace of your model or your viewmodel?`RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.TicketVM`

Comment: @DCruz22 namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels

Answer (score 2):

I gave you that code (from [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOiFs2)) but its clear you have not understood anything about it.

Delete your `Create()` methods and rename the `Index()` methods to `Create()`.

And if you want an additional SelectList in your view for `Categories`, then add a properties (say)

```
public int Category{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
```

to the view model (don't use `ViewBag` when you using a view model) and put the code for populating the collection in the `ConfigureViewModel()` method.

The `Edit` methods will be similar to the code currently shown in the `Index()` methods, the main difference if that you get the existing data model based on the ID, and map its properties to a new instance of `TicketVM` before passing the view model to the view. And in the POST method, you get the data model again based on the ID, and map the view model properties to it, then save the data model.

Comment: I re-edited the Create and Edit methods in my controller but I don't know what to do for  ` public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)`  You said there is a POST method so is that the Create method)? Regarding the `ViewBag` I don't know what else to use . If I take out the Index then wouldn't it stop me from getting to a page where it shows all my tickets when I click Tickets ?

Comment: You really are confused :). No time now but I'll add a few notes later. But basically `DotNetFiddle` only allows you to create one view named `Index` so that why its what it is. The code in the `DotNetFiddle` if for your `Create()` methods so you can still have an `Index()` method for displaying a list.

Comment: Yeah your method is better but it is far too complicated for a beginner like me to understand. I'll probably need to be spoon fed this to be able to understand what you are trying to show me. I'm only following one site mostly to learn how to use this MVC Entity framework which forces me to follow that model hence the Administrator Class.

Comment: I'll update the answer with more detail later but no time now. But why do you have a dropdownlist for all users. Surely a user cant create a `Ticket` for another user?

Comment: Yeah's that's true. I haven't gotten to that extent yet. Right now I also have an Accounts database which will store all the usernames(Users) and passwords so that in the future when users register into my system the UserID and Name will  "somehow" be linked to the Accounts database . I still haven't thought of a way to execute that.

Comment: Now you seem to have changed your original question and its not even clear what your problem is (and FGS, get rid of those `ViewBag` properties and use your view model)

Comment: And in future, do not change the original question. A lot of users have gone to a lot of trouble to give comments and answers, and you have now invalidated all of them.

Comment: Well I changed the code as close as possible to yours and now my Ticket page comes up with ` Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.` My ticket page is gone and I have no drop down list so I'm pretty much worse than when I got rid of my Admin Class. I have no idea why I need a Ticket VM and I don't know what ViewModel does.

Comment: What is causing the error? What 'Ticket' page? No one here is psychic.

Comment: Well I'm assuming it's Views\Tickets\Create.cshtml because thats the file which you told me to modify so now when I click on my Ticket tab on my site it shows me `Server Error in '/' Application.` and `The resource cannot be found.` I've uploaded the photo.

Comment: What 'Ticket' tab? Is that something in another view? How do you expect me to guess what other mistakes you have made in code you have not even shown. Ask a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: Take a look again. I've uploaded the page. There were no errors before I listened to your solution of deleting the admin class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106426/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jason-wan).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get those values from a view model but you are not passing that view model from your controller to your view. If you use `DropDownListFor`, you need to initialize your `AdministratorList` property in your controller first and pass it to the view `View(model)`. If you go for the ViewBag option, you don't need to pass the viewmodel but you need to use `DropDownList` in your view like this:

```
ViewBag.MyDropdownList = new SelectList(Items, "PropertyOfItemUsedForValue", "PropertyOfItemUsedForText");
```

And then in your view add your dropdown like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyDropdownList", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to bind the dropdownlist in Enity then,

https://csharpimp.blogspot.in/2015/12/how-to-bind-dropdown-with-multiple-columns-using-entity-framework.html